# How to add multiple image to timeline in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter Bootstrap v3.3.1. I need to add multiple images to my timeline panel and out put should be like this

[image]

this is the code that I’m using.Image gallery must be inside the timeline-body

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
         <div class="well-lg panel-body">
            <div class="timeline-panel">
               <div class="timeline-heading">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-left">
                           <a href="#">
                           <img class="media-object" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/43a5669f2e4d2342701ed560d453a0dd?s=50&d=&r=G" alt="...">
                           </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                           <h4 class=" media-heading timeline-title">Mussum ipsum cacilds</h4>
                           <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 11 hours ago via Twitter</small></p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="timeline-body">
               </div>
               <div class="timeline-footer">
                  <a><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" style="font-size: 20px;"></i></a>
                  <a class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="font-size: 13px;"></i></a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this? is there are any sample code that I can use or any plug-in ?

Comment: Isn't this a copy of Facebook? `:P`

Comment: hmm yap smiler ;) do you know how to do this ?

Comment: Why not check Masonry.js?

Comment: hmm I checked that also but I don't understand to use it to get what I expected?

Comment: Er... Well... Lemme see if I can find something similar.

Answer (score 1):

you only need to use float and clear, no plugin or whatever to generate that simple CSS should be needed.

```css
.fesse-bouc {
  padding-top: 2px;
  width: 476px;
  border: solid 1px;
  background: turquoise;
}
.fesse-bouc img:first-of-type,
img:first-of-type + img {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.fesse-bouc img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fesse-bouc">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/235x235/" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/235x235/" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/235x156/" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/235x156/" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/235x156/" />
</div>
```

Comment: @user3480706 ??  where is it not doing the job http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Veaoor ?? IF it is not a CSS matter , remove the tag and rephrase the question. bootstrap is about styling ;)

Comment: I have a question if add ten images to inside the div tag can I get the smiler out come as what I expect i meant click the image and go through each images? I don't understand that why I’m asking

Comment: @user3480706 okay i see better now, you look for a carrousel showing up in sort of lightbox modal. I do not think there is such ready made plugin, (unless a facebook api), you 'll have to devellop this. nobody will do it here from scratch, but plenty will help you once you 'll start